# double subscript error while compiling in italics mode

Tags: equations, italic

I am a beginner in latex. I am getting double subscript error while compiling the eqn below. pls help

```
\textit{$[S_e]_e_=_1^N$}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What's the `\textit` command for?

Comment: to get the text in italics

Comment: What are the `_` (underscore) symbols supposed to achieve? Are you trying to create subscript material? If so, why are there `_` symbols to the left and right of `=`? And, is the `^` symbol supposed to create a superscript? Please advise.

Comment: Which text? You have a math formula, and this does nothing. Anyway, in maths, all letters are already in italic.

Answer (score 11):

To have more than one letter in subscript, put the text in curly braces (`{`and `}`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

$[S_e]_{e=1}^N$

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: Math equation]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, slightly aesthetic, to the answer of @Tom you can use `\scriptscriptstyle` in mathmode to decrease the subscript `$e=1$`. Thus `N` and `e=1` have a bit more distance.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$[S_e]_{\scriptscriptstyle e=1}^N$
\end{document}
```

Comment: using `\scalebox` for text give bad results. Never do this!

Comment: @TeXisFun I have delete `\scalebox`.